# I am unable to write delete condition for specific id using fetch for FIREBASE

Tags: reactjs

In firebase, I am having only single data entry schema, `name:value`, and I want to delete specific item from the list when clicked on delete button. I am getting the correct console output -- which id to delete/which name to delete.

How do I write correct delete condition for this name/where to put delete condition, as per below code:

```js
function removethisitem(props) {
  //console.log(props.id+"   id to be delted");
  //console.log(props.name+"   name to be delted");
    
  const deletelist = async()=> { 
    const response=await fetch(url, {
      method: 'DELETE',
      body:JSON.stringify({
        name:props.name,
      })
    });
  };
  deletelist();
};
```